# How to determine who uploaded file

Tags: php, javascript

I have a system that allows users to upload .doc files..I'm using PHP and renaming these files the memberid.doc  so that I can determine which user uploaded that file and give him the option to delete that file. I would like to keep the file name the same though. Is there any way I can do this and still track which user uploaded that file?

Comment: Where are you currently storing the files? What do you want to do if two users upload a file of the same name?

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a MySQL database of filenames and by which user they were uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will store the files in the same folder, and worrying if a file of the same name is uploaded it would delete the older file, to prevent it from happening u have to give a new name to the file that is stored in server (something related to the user id)
the table would be 
**user_id filename serverFileName**

filename would be name of file the user uploaded, like android.jpg
serverFilename would be the name file as stored in server like user4_1.jpg